# Schematron calculation tests for optional elements

Tags: xml, option-type, schematron

I need to create set of Schematron rules testing calculations in an XML Invoice. The problem is that some of the tested elements are optional and my rules fail when the tested elements are mjissing. How do I specify something like: "test value if the element is present"?

The XML instance excerpt:

```
<invoice>
<invoiceLineItem number="1">
    <invoicedQuantity>50</invoicedQuantity>
    <amountExclusiveAllowancesCharges>500</amountExclusiveAllowancesCharges>
    <amountInclusiveAllowancesCharges>455</amountInclusiveAllowancesCharges>
    <itemPrice>10</itemPrice>
    <invoiceAllowanceChargeAmount>45</invoiceAllowanceChargeAmount>
</invoiceLineItem>
<invoiceLineItem number="2">
    <invoicedQuantity>10</invoicedQuantity>
    <amountExclusiveAllowancesCharges>150</amountExclusiveAllowancesCharges>
    <itemPrice>15</itemPrice>
</invoiceLineItem>
</invoice>
```

My Schematron checking the calculation:

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron">
    <sch:pattern name="Check calculation in invoicelineItem">
        <sch:rule context="invoiceLineItem">
            <sch:assert test="amountExclusiveAllowancesCharges = invoicedQuantity * itemPrice">The amountExclusiveAllowancesCharges calculation is incorrect.</sch:assert>
            <sch:assert test="amountInclusiveAllowancesCharges = (invoicedQuantity * itemPrice) - invoiceAllowanceChargeAmount">The amountInclusiveAllowancesCharges calculation is incorrect.</sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

It fails when the amountInclusiveAllowancesCharges and invoiceAllowanceChargeAmount are missing (they are optional.

I'll be grateful for any useful tips,

Ewa

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is to late, but if not or some one else have a similar question:

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron">
    <sch:pattern name="Check calculation in invoicelineItem">
        <sch:rule context="invoiceLineItem">
            <sch:assert test="amountExclusiveAllowancesCharges = invoicedQuantity * itemPrice">The amountExclusiveAllowancesCharges calculation is incorrect.</sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
    <sch:pattern name="Check calculation in invoicelineItem (inclusive)">
        <sch:rule context="invoiceLineItem[amountInclusiveAllowancesCharges][invoiceAllowanceChargeAmount]">
            <sch:assert test="amountInclusiveAllowancesCharges = (invoicedQuantity * itemPrice) - invoiceAllowanceChargeAmount">The amountInclusiveAllowancesCharges calculation is incorrect.</sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

- You need two rules, because you want to validate the invoiceLineItem
  every time for the exclusives but the inclusives just if they are
  available
  (`context="invoiceLineItem[amountInclusiveAllowancesCharges][invoiceAllowanceChargeAmount]"`).
- You need two patterns because of this: http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/escali_xsm/escali-ext_en.html#sqf:d109e234
- Any thing else is the same